# Populating a List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Pretty much beginner in Swift and self-learning through online tutorials. So I am creating List view, the data (array) for List view is kept in a separate Swift file.

In the code below the data from array is imported and it populates the List using List syntax and Closure. My question is how Swift Closure helps in populating this data, may be a step by step explanation would help. I am facing an understanding challenge as I move further in the course.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    let hikes = Hike.all()  //all the data kept in separate Swift file

    var body: some View {
        List(self.hikes, id: \.name) { hike in  //how does closure help here?  
            Text(hike.name)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: The closure gets called once for each element in the array used as the first parameter to List, this works similar to functions like `map`, `filter` etc if that is of any help. Not sure what kind of explanation you are expecting here.

Comment: Thanks. does the variable hike loops in like "For-In" loop till all the values are printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an explanation at a rather high level of abstraction.

**What is a `List`?**

A `List` is a view that can represent a list of your models (in this case, `self.hikes`. I don't see this declared anywhere though, did you mean `self.imgs`?). Each one of your models is represented as a "subview" of the `List`.

**What is a closure?**

A closure is really just a function. It can take any number of parameters, and optionally return a value.

**So why is a closure used here?**

`List` doesn't actually know how should represent each of your models as a `View`, so it needs to ask *you*. It does this with a closure, which takes one of your models as a parameter, and returns a `View`. This is so that whenever the `List` wants to ask the question "How should I represent this model?", it can just call the closure, and it will get a `View`.

In your case, you have said that to represent one of your models `hike`, the `List` should use a `Text` view with the string `hike.name`.

In other words, the closure you pass in here represents the mapping between your model and the view that shows your model.

<sub>Note: the closure you've used here is actually a special type of closures called function builders. Read more [here](https://blog.vihan.org/swift-function-builders/) if you are interested.</sub>

From your comment:

> does the variable hike loops in like "For-In" loop till all the values are printed

Well, it doesn't necessarily work like a for-in loop. It's really all up to the implementation of `List`. The answer to "when will the closure be called?" is "when the `List` needs a view".

Comment: it was a very clear explanation. Thank you so much.